# What does a backslash mean in TCL?

Tags: parameters, tcl

I have a question about "\" in TCL

I see a piece of code as following:

```
proc ::A::B {c \
             d \
             e \
             f 
}
```

what does this "\" mean in the parameter list?

can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As stated in the [language definition](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/Tcl.htm#M24),

> **\<newline>***whiteSpace*
>
> > A single space character replaces the backslash, newline, and all spaces and tabs after the newline. This backslash sequence is unique in that it is replaced in a separate pre-pass before the command is actually parsed. This means that it will be replaced even when it occurs between braces, and the resulting space will be treated as a word separator if it is not in braces or quotes.

This means that your sample:

```
proc ::A::B {c \
             d \
             e \
             f 
}
```

is *exactly* equivalent to this (note the spacing):

```
proc ::A::B {c  d  e  f 
}
```

Given that this would be an invalid call of the normal `proc` command, I suspect you've trimmed your sample code a bit. :-)

Answer (score 5):

The backslash `\` at the end of a line in Tcl indicates *line continuation*. So your statement is exactly the same as:

```
proc ::A::B {c d e f}
```

except it's broken up across more than one source line.

Comment: You have to be careful that the backslash is the very last character on the line. I've been bitten in the past where there is a space after it which negates the special-ness of backslash-newline. Using an editor that can highline end-of-line is helpful.

Comment: Technically, it's the same as {c  d  e  f}. Note the two spaces between the characters. The backslash escapes the newline plus any following whitespace into a single space. Since there was a space before the backslash, you wind up with two spaces total.